# Concat textbox name with string

Tags: ms-access

greetings for all access experts in this forum

I got problems when trying to concat between my text box name with string.

In my form there are 10 textboxs named : Student1, Student2, Student3...Student10

I tried to get value from each textbox

This is my code :

```
Dim a as string
a = 1
do until a = 2
MsgBox (Me.Controls("Student"&a).Value)
loop
```

It's not working. No error also.

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: You've declared `a` as a string, then attempted to use it as an integer in a loop, and then you never increment it.  Have you stepped through your code?

Comment: Ups sorry, I paste wrong code.

Dim a as string
a = 1
do until a = 2
  MsgBox (Me.Controls("Student"&a).Value)
  a = a+1
loop

Yes, you're right it should be Integer. 
It works now. 
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Try something more like this:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 3
    MsgBox Nz(Me.Controls("Student" & i).Value, "")
Next
```

Comment: Hi Gord,

I've tried it and it's works! 
I've been searching it all day.
Thank you so much for your help.